# Somando inteiros consecutivos em uma lista - Python

Tags: python-2.7

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
i = -0
soma = 0
lista = [1,2,3,4]
for i in xrage(0,len(lista)):
    if lista[i] != lista[i+1]:
        soma += lista[i]
    i+=1
print soma
```

Está dando o seguinte erro: `IndexError: list index out of range.`

Como faço pra resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cigano Morrison já lhe deu a solução para esse problema. Mas, se me permite vou dar-lhe sugestões de correção:

Porquê o `i = 0` no inicio? Não é necessário, o valor do `i` na primeira volta do ciclo for já vai ser 0 porque o seu `xrange(0,len(lista)): ...` começa em 0.

Escusa de incrementar 1 ao `i` no final do loop, a construção do ciclo `for` já está a fazer isso automáticamente

Ou seja, ficaria:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4]
soma = lista[0]

for i in xrange(0, len(lista) - 1):
    if lista[i] != lista[i + 1]:
        soma += lista[i + 1]

print soma # 10
```

É de notar de com este código você só vai adicionar à `soma` caso dois valores da lista não sejam iguais nem consecutivos, por causa da condição `if lista[i] != lista[i + 1]: ...`.

Ou seja se a lista fosse `[1,2,2,2]` o resultado seria 3, pois o segundo e o ultimo 2 (`lista[2]`, `lista[3]`), que têm valores iguais aos elementos anteriores, não iriam ser contados.

PS: Cuidado com o titulo da pergunta "Somando inteiros consecutivos", porque o que está a fazer com esse código (se for mesmo essa lógica que apresentou) é mais "Somando inteiros que não sejam iguais nem consecutivos"

Answer (score 0):

Porque você está lendo uma posição que não existe quando `i == 3` (última iteração). O correto seria:

```
i = 0
soma = 0
lista = [1,2,3,4]
soma += lista[0]

for i in xrange(0, len(lista) - 1):
    if lista[i] != lista[i + 1]:
        soma += lista[i + 1]
    i += 1

print soma
```